# Why is $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$ enough accurate for integration?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

I would like to understand from a perturbative - geometric argument why we can use $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$ to compute length of curves and not something "more precise" (because here it is just a linear approximation of the curve). To give you ideas of what I am expecting as explanation, I will give you how I understand the fact that the infinitesimal area $dA$ under the curve is $dA=f(x)dx$ (and not something "more precise").

---

When we want to compute areas of curve using the integration, we implicitly go back to a Riemann serie by doing the following stuff :

[image]

Imagine we want to compute the area under the curve between the abscisses $a$ and $b$. We know that the infinitesimal area to integrate will be $dA=f(x)dx$. I will show how I understand that it is a good enough ""approximation"".

Imagine we would take as area the total area of the polygon $(ABDC)$. We would have :

$$dA=dx*( \frac{1}{2}(f(x+dx)-f(x))+f(x))$$

Where $x$ is the abscisse in $A$.

We will see that we don't need the term in $dx^2$ : it will vanish in the Riemann sum.

We write : $dx=\frac{b-a}{N}$ and we write the Riemann summation.

The total area under the curve will be :

$$A=\lim_{N \to \infty} (\frac{b-a}{N}) \bigg [\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^N (f(a+(k+1)*\frac{b-a}{N})-f(a+k*\frac{b-a}{N})) +\sum_{k=0}^N f(a+k*\frac{b-a}{N})  \bigg ]$$

$$A=\lim_{N \to \infty} (\frac{b-a}{N}) \bigg [\frac{1}{2} (f(b+\frac{b-a}{N})-f(a)) +\sum_{k=0}^N f(a+k*\frac{b-a}{N})  \bigg ]$$

(The first sum is just a telescoping one). And finally :

$$A=\lim_{N \to \infty} (\frac{b-a}{N}) \bigg [\sum_{k=0}^N f(a+k*\frac{b-a}{N})  \bigg ]$$

Indeed, as N goes to infinity, the first term in the bracket will vanish.

So we find the "usual" Riemann sum and we understand now that it is not necessary to take terms in $dx^2$ : we can ""approximate"" $dA$ by neglecting the area of the triangle as this term will vanish when we will take $N$ to infinity.

---

Now, my question :

I would like to do the same stuff to see that when we want to compute the length of a curve, we can take $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$ as a good enough "approximation" because more precised term will vanish in Riemann integration.

To do it I tried to consider an approximation of $ds$ by a parabola, but then I need to know the length of an arc of parabola. But to do it I need to know the length of an arc of parabola and things go round and round in circles and I am stuck.

**I really would like a geometrical interpretation of this**, there are formal proof that $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$ but they don't help to really understand what is behind (in my opinion). Furthermore such interpretations help to really understand the method to obtain differential equation (like the obtention of the equation of heat for example).

Comment: Fundamentally, it is a consequence of local linearity. If you consider an exact arc length $\Delta s$ corresponding to $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$ then it can be shown that $$\lim_{\Delta x\to 0+}\frac{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}{\Delta s^2}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0+}\frac{\left[1+\left(\frac {dy}{dx}\right)^2\right]\Delta x^2}{\Delta s^2}=1$$ pointwise everywhere, given a few conditions on the function of interest

Comment: You argument for $dA=f(x)dx$ being a good enough approximation relies on the assumption that considering $ABDC$ as a trapezoid is a good enough approximation.  How do we know that?  Your method for justifying an approximation always must rely on the previous justification of another approximation, which must in turn rely on even another approximation being justified before that, *ad infinitum*.

Comment: @JoshuaMeyers I agree, i didn't say that I have a totally rigorous proof. I just wanted to show that adding the top triangle of the trapezoid for the computation of the integral is useless as this term vanishes in the Riemann summation. If I like this vision of the integral it is because it is helpfull to understand what we do in physics when we say "lets take an element dx of length, we apply on it newton laws by assuming they don't vary on dx". It helps me to understand well the mathematical method used in physics and why they are valid